# Items on a map in a RecyclerView are not fully displayed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I have a RecyclerView and I want to display a list of items in it. I have created the layout for each individual element so far. The problem is that not everything is displayed. The data is all there, that's not the reason, it's all about the display.

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rv_list_main_img"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/longtime"></ImageView>

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_img"
                    android:background="@drawable/imageborder"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"

                    android:src="@drawable/shorttime"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"></ImageView>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Abador"
                    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/baumans"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_place"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Bella Vista, PY"
                    android:textSize="16sp"></TextView>


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_price"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="600 USD/mtl"
                    android:textSize="23sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_desc"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_message_btn"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/send"></ImageButton>

    </LinearLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

An item in the list should look like this:

[image]

And this is how it is presented:

[image]

As you can see, the smaller image is truncated and all of the text underneath is not even displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make your view height wrap and textview height wrap(Copy th)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="10dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rv_list_main_img"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_img"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_sender_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="Abador"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_place"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Bella Vista, PY"
                android:textSize="16sp" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_price"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:text="600 USD/mtl"
                android:textSize="23sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_desc"
                android:layout_width="260dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:maxLength="200"
                android:maxLines="2"
                android:text="Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe Beschreibung Haus sdf sdfe"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />


            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/main_list_rv_message_btn"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your CardView `android:layout_height="wrap_parent"`